# Некорректно работает last-child во Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Есть список элементов, которые отрисовываются через v-for.
На каждом из них есть динамический класс **numbers-filled**.
last-child срабатывает на самом последнем в родителе элементе с классом **numbers-filled**.
Проблема вот в чём, когда последний элемент теряет этот класс, то по логике last-child должен сработать на **предпоследнем**, но не работает - на нём не появляется свойство ::after

[image: last-child сработал]

[image: last-child не сработал]

Comment: Приводите воспроизводимый код в виде сниппета (иконка файла c "<>"), включая Ваш CSS. Пока конкретно понять проблему сложно.

Comment: Если мы говорим о CSS-псевдоклассе `::last-child`, то это буквально «последний ребёнок». Ваш `span.numbes-fiiled` не последний (после него есть ещё один span), а у последнего нет класса `.numbers-filled`, поэтому ничего и не появляется.

Comment: Alexey Ten, я подозревал, что проблема в этом, но я же ставлю стиль под класс .numbes-fiiled, т.е. ожидаю, что стиль применится именно к последнему спану с таким классом.